# Trying to run simplest WCF service ever - doesn't work

Tags: .net, wcf

I'm trying to run a simple WCF service hosted within console application. Here's the code I have:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var serviceHost = new ServiceHost(
          typeof (MyService), new Uri("http://localhost:3000"));
        serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(
          typeof (IMyService), new WebHttpBinding(), "");

        serviceHost.Open();
        Console.ReadKey();
        serviceHost.Close();
    }
}

[ServiceContract]
public interface IMyService
{
    [WebGet]
    [OperationContract]
    string Hello(String s);
}

public class MyService : IMyService
{
    public string Hello(String s)
    {
        return "hello " + s;
    }
}
```

When I go to `http://localhost:3000`, it says

> Service
>
> This is a Windows© Communication Foundation service.
>
> Metadata publishing for this service is currently disabled.
>
> If you have access to the service, you can enable metadata publishing by completing the following steps to modify your web or application configuration file:
>
> [more text here]

Then, when I go to `http://localhost:3000/Hello?s=John`, it says:

> The message with To 'http://localhost:3000/Hello?s=John' cannot be processed at the receiver, due to an AddressFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher. Check that the sender and receiver's EndpointAddresses agree.

I'm wondering whether I'm doing it wrong. Target platform is .NET 4. I have no `app.config`.

Will appreciate any advices.

Comment: You do not have an app.config out of principle?

Comment: This is the first time I'm using WCF, so I decided to make this hello world as simple as possible. Is app.config absolutely **required**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed like this:

```
var serviceHost = new ServiceHost(
  typeof(MyService), new Uri("http://localhost:3000"));
var serviceContractDescription = ContractDescription.GetContract(
  typeof (IMyService));
var serviceEndpoint = new WebHttpEndpoint(
  serviceContractDescription, new EndpointAddress("http://localhost:3000"));
serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(serviceEndpoint);
```

Works now.

Comment: This works, but is a LOT harder than it needs to be. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

In .NET 4 or later if you define a base address, WCF will generate default endpoints for you. In other words just do:

```
var serviceHost = new ServiceHost(
      typeof (MyService), new Uri("http://localhost:3000")); 
serviceHost.Open();
```

Read the **Default Endpoints** section in [A Developer's Introduction to Windows Communication Foundation 4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee354381.aspx)